# MVC failing to match default action when controller name matches folder name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-controller

I'm running into a bizarre problem trying to establish a non-conventional folder structure for my MVC project:

```
\Franchises\Compliance\FeesPaid\FeesPaidController
\Franchises\Compliance\FeesPaid\Views\..
\Franchises\Compliance\FeesPaid\ViewModels\..
```

My plan is to have 1 controller in each sub folder, along with associated views/viewmodels folders. I prefer not to have a /Controllers/ folder which will only ever contain a single class.

For testing purposes I am manually routing like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("whocares", "Franchises/Compliance/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "FeesPaid", 
                  action = "Index", 
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

I run into mysterious behavior. These URLs route correctly:

```
http://localhost:12345/Franchises/Compliance/FeesPaid/Index
http://localhost:12345/Franchises/Compliance/FeesPaid/Index/123
```

But this URL fails with "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory" error:

```
http://localhost:12345/Franchises/Compliance/FeesPaid
```

I found this only occurs when the Controller name matches the folder name (minus "*Controller"). So fudging the controller name to something else makes it work:

```
\Franchises\Compliance\FeesPaid\FeesPaidXController

http://localhost:12345/Franchises/Compliance/FeesPaidX
http://localhost:12345/Franchises/Compliance/FeesPaidX/Index
http://localhost:12345/Franchises/Compliance/FeesPaidX/Index/123
```

Why would a controller & folder having matching names cause it to fail when the URL relies on default action & id?

**edit**

On investigation it turns out that IIS is routing the request to DirectoryListingModule instead of MVC, so it's not even reaching MVC routing.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"  >  <--- attribute added
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>

<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"  >
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
    <remove name="DirectoryListingModule"/>    <--- Fails to start web app with "lock violation"
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

How can I force IIS to route these requests to MVC instead of DirectoryListingModule? Preferably without IIS configuration changes I may not have control over in production.

Comment: Just as a note, the directory containing the controllers is not related in any way to the MapRoutes.  For example, your controllers could all be in the root of the project, and as long as the Request Url matches the MapRoute, the controllers will execute.

Comment: What happens if you browse to `http://localhost:12345/Franchises/Compliance/FeesPaid/` (notice the extra end slash).

Comment: An extra slash at the end does not make any difference. Somehow, MVC is missing the route, and the request is going to some generic directory listing module instead.

Comment: It may be just a ASP.Net *feature*, in your web.config, what if you enable (set to true):  `<system.webServer><modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`?  I bet it works.

Comment: It seems to be related to this, I am investigating further: http://forums.asp.net/t/1251156.aspx?How+to+create+a+flipcart+like+panel+for+showing+products+in+gridview

Comment: Yes, by default IIS will attempt to serve existing files, since you created a directory structure that match the url, it will attempt to server the file.  That post also talks about *work-arounds*.  The correct solution is not to create a directory (because it will either not exist or be empty on the server when the application is deployed).

Comment: You're on the right track here - IIS is routing it to DirectoryListingModule so it's not even hitting MVC. Unfortunately  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" didn't make any difference. How else can I force it to ignore DirectoryListingModule? (without modifying IIS configuration)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47708/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-brendan-hill)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's comments.

Further investigation has lead me to post another question here:

[How to disable or reprioritize IIS DirectoryListingModule under MVC module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842206/how-to-disable-or-reprioritize-iis-directorylistingmodule-under-mvc-module)