# How to route a request for a directory that exists on disk to ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app (using .NET framework 4.5) with extensionless URLs. The site contains some static files, but all extensionless requests *should* go into MVC routing.

It all works fine for requests like:

- /
- /news
- /fr/news

However if I make a request for /fr I get the error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden, 
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

I understand that this is because there actually exists a /fr directory on disk, however I still want to map this  request to my MVC app. It is not an option to remove the fr directory, as it contains some static files.

Is this possible? I have tried adding `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` to the modules element in system.webServer (I don't really want to do this, but it didn't help anyway).

Edit - in case its useful, here is the routing:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("cid/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
           "Page",
           "{*PageId}",
           new { controller = "Page", action = "Page" }, // Parameter defaults
           new { pageId = @"^(.*)?$" } // Parameter constraints
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: I added the routing, though I am not sure this is relevant, as MVC Routing never kicks in for the /fr request. I am pretty sure this is due to the DirectoryListingModule picking it up, but I am unable to get this out of the picture (as described at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842206/how-to-disable-or-reprioritize-iis-directorylistingmodule-under-mvc-module)

Comment: Have a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/17336588/3383479](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17336588/3383479)

Comment: Not sure how that helps, as stated I cannot delete the /fr directory

Comment: What do you want to happen for the /fr request in your app? Did you create a FrController, containing an Index() action?

Comment: All requests go through the main Page controller and Page action, which basically loads in content from a CMS based on the URL. The default route is not used for URL requests

Comment: I think you're on the right track by adding runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true. I suspect the default route handler is passing the /fr request to the directory handler which explains the IIS error above. How about creating a custom route handler to intercept the /fr request and route it to the MVC controller instead?

Comment: The problem is that this web app is generic, so on one implementation it could be /fr but in another it could be /de or other language variant(s) I guess I could make the routes configurable, but I would prefer not too, to keep custom config to a minimum, however if there is no other way, this will have to be it.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to prevent access to local folders and files is to set `RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles` flag to let ASP.NET handle URLs targeting physical files. So change your route register to:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("cid/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
    routes.MapRoute(
       "Page",
       "{*PageId}",
       new { controller = "Page", action = "Page" }, // Parameter defaults
       new { pageId = @"^(.*)?$" } // Parameter constraints
    );
}
```

Your `"Default"` route is not required as `"Page"` is really a catch-all case.

Another method is to change IIS configuration to give ASP.NET MVC routing higher priority than IIS directory listing. In IIS7, got to your website, select Modules from IIS section, and then View Ordered List from Actions tab. Move UrlRoutingModule above DirectoryListingModule.

---

As a side note, from your comments I understand that you have a single controller with a single action. The action will serve all requests, apart from the static resources defined with `IgnoreRoute`. This is not a recommended setup as you loose all the benefits of MVC architecture. Moreover, you will find that your Page action will grow rapidly to include more and more cases. This is exactly what routing and controllers were designed to solve.

If you reckon a single catch-all method is the best solution for you, than you don't really need MVC and you would be better off using Web API which has much smaller request overhead.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid pushing requests for physical files thru the MVC routing, as I cannot imagine that this would not have any performance impact for my statics.

Comment: Thanks for the extra advice on MVC architecture, however don't worry - it is a 'proper' MVC architecture! The application is hooked up to a CMS, so when a request comes in, we first map the request url to a page object in the CMS, which defines a set of sub actions to fire (which use the default route and normal MVC stuff using a bunch of controllers, actions and views)

Comment: @Will No doubt the routing has a performance impact, but it might be smaller that you think. ASP.NET tries to push to IIS as much of request handling as possible, and IIS handlers are quiet good at caching. So if your setup is ASP.NET 4.0 + hosted on IIS 7 +, then I wouldn't worry too much about the performance. Have a look here for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx

Comment: Although my solution is somewhat different to yours - you get the bounty for putting the effort in and getting me to think it through again!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I initially thought that it was necessary to remove the DirectoryListingModule, but this is not the case, my custom HttpModule rewrite kicks in before this, so it can be left in.

The workaround I used to fix this was to add some logic to a custom HttpModule which was doing some request processing. Here I detect if the request corresponds to the root of one of my localizations (/fr/ /es/ etc.) and if so, rewrite the url to the default page /fr/index, for which the routing works as normal.

```
private void BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;
    var url = context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    if (IsLocalizationRoot(url))
    {
        context.RewritePath(url + GetDefaultPageName());
    }
}
```

If you are interested in how to remove the DirectoryListingModule (as mentioned above, this is not necessary, but its useful info anyway):

As the StaticFileHandler references it, you need to remove it and remove and re-add the StaticFileHandler (without the DirectoryListingModule) in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="StaticFile"/>
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule" 
           resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />  
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="DirectoryListingModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

This will probably cause a HTTP 500 error, due to a lock violation. You need to unlock it in the IIS applicationHost.config:

open a command prompt (run as Administrator) and go to C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv

```
appcmd set module DirectoryListingModule /lockItem:false
```

Comment: While this works - it feels like a bit of a workaround and so I am wondering if there is a pure config solution, which does not involve an HTTP Module, or routing static requests through MVC...

Comment: Its also not a generic solution to the issue of existing directories not being routed - although it works for my use case